# Parallelize remote service calls

Tags: java, spring, soap, task

In my current work, for a use case we are making several remote service calls (SOAP over HTTP) in **sequence**. These are independent calls and I have to collate the data from each call and finally prepare my response. I want to parallelize these calls.

Comment: What framework are you using currently to invoke your webservices?

Comment: I am using Sun Metro for invoking the services.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you should use an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Make a class that performs your query and implements [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html). You can then submit instances of this class to an `Executor` and it will look after running this in multiple threads (pooling etc. - all configurable). You get given back a [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object for each submission and you simply call `get()` on that to get your result.

The framework means you don't have to worry about instantiating threads, setting up pooling, determining what's run etc.

Here's [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html).

Comment: Brian, Is it a good idea to create own threads inside a Java EE container?

Answer (score 0):

Spawning threads in Java EE is a no-go we're told. However, the OP doesn't say whether Java EE or Java SE is used.

For Java EE the [WorkManager API](http://workmanager.blogspot.ch/) may be useful.

Other than that yes, `ExecutorService` or [Spring TaskScheduler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) (rather unlikely if I got the problem right).